# why does "<" throw an error inside a button, but not ">"?

Tags: html, xml, button

I have two buttons i use for scrolling, made just with text inside a button:

[image: Buttons]

```
<div class="trend-header scroll"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="scrollButtonClick(0)" > < </button>
    <button type="button" onclick="scrollButtonClick(1)" > > </button>
</div>
```

The first one throws an "XML formatting error". I get my errors in finnish but i'm pretty sure that's a direct translation. The problem is most likely the "<" text inside my button, because the error message says it's on line 18, column 69, where the text is. It's also red when i click the link inside the error message. Is there an easy way to get around this? I tried putting the '<' inside quotes, but that just threw an error and looked ugly. It's not the space around the '<'. That's pretty much all i could think of that would fix this. Google gives very general results about buttons and XML so it wasn't of any help.

Here is my css if it matters?

```
.trend-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.trend-header.scroll {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: A `<` can be the start of an html element. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` has a special meaning in XML and HTML. The parser now expects you to provide an element name (just like you did previously with e.g. `<button`).

If you want to encode a literal `<` instead, use `&lt;`. While less often misrepresented, to get proper XML, use `&gt;` instead of `>`, and `&amp;` instead of `&`.

There's other cases where you might need other escapes; for further information, see something like [this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes). Generally, you're looking for character escaping.

Answer (score 2):

As for your headline question, XML always requires `<` to be escaped (as `&lt;`) so it's not mistaken for the beginning of a start or end tag, but `>` only needs to be escaped under particular circumstances, in particular when it's part of the sequence `]]>`.